# AIR app inactive = lower framerate?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I'm working in a quite uncomfortable setup and I'm trying to figure out how I can fix it.

I'm developing an AIR app that is receiving TUIO events from a Framework for a fiducial marker based multitouch table. Until yesterday I was faking the events by mouse to work faster, but then I connected everything to a TUIO simulator and the problems appeared.

The TUIO Simulator is a java app. By dragging markers on the simulator you can send OSC messages that I'm forwarding to my AIR app. The problem is that I'm noticing that when I drag something on the simulator, my AIR app lose the focus, and the AIR framerate suddendly drops. If I drag something on my simulator and I switch super fast to the AIR window, everything goes smooth, so it seems the problem is that if my AIR app is not the active app it's redrawn at a lower framerate (I remember reading something about this, not sure).

So my questions are: am I right about the fact that inactive windows in AIR are redrawn at lower framerate? do you have any suggestion/workaround to fix it and to allow me to interactive with the java app without my AIR framerate drops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, I figured out the solution by writing the question :)
I just added:

```
 this.stage.addEventListener ( Event.DEACTIVATE, onDeactivate ); 
 private function onDeactivate (evt:Event):void {
      stage.frameRate = 60;
 }
```

In my main class, and everything is fixed.
I post the answer for people that could have the same problem in the future